# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GTMSessionFetcher/Core" RNFBAuth (from ../@react-native-firebase/auth`) was resolved to 16.5.0

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, podfile

I get errors while trying to pod install in my app I deleted the lock podfile.lock and also update the repo but I still have problems with the Firebase product sometime with auth and sometimes with dynamiclink or analytics i also try to delete node_modules but still the same problem

## podfile

```
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'App' do

rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])


  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'


  pod 'RNSVG', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-svg'

  pod 'react-native-fbsdk', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk'

  pod 'RNGestureHandler', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler'

  pod 'RNReanimated', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-reanimated'

  pod 'react-native-viewpager', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/viewpager'

  pod 'RNSound', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-sound'

  pod 'ReactNativeGetLocation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-get-location'
  pod 'react-native-camera', path: '../node_modules/react-native-camera', subspecs: [
    'BarcodeDetectorMLKit'
  ]

  target 'AppTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!({'Flipper' => '0.87.0' , 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5.3' , 'Flipper-RSocket' => '1.3.1' })
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end
```

## the error i get :

````
  In Podfile:
    RNFBAuth (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth`) was resolved to 16.5.0, which depends on
      Firebase/Auth (= 10.3.0) was resolved to 10.3.0, which depends on
        FirebaseAuth (~> 10.3.0) was resolved to 10.3.0, which depends on
          GTMSessionFetcher/Core (< 4.0, >= 2.1)

    RNGoogleSignin (from `../node_modules/@react-native-community/google-signin`) was resolved to 4.0.3, which depends on
      GoogleSignIn (~> 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
        GTMAppAuth (~> 1.0) was resolved to 1.3.1, which depends on
          GTMSessionFetcher/Core (< 3.0, >= 1.5)

    RNGoogleSignin (from `../node_modules/@react-native-community/google-signin`) was resolved to 4.0.3, which depends on
      GoogleSignIn (~> 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
        GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.1)

CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleMaps":
  In Podfile:
    react-native-google-maps (from `../node_modules/react-native-maps`) was resolved to 0.28.0, which depends on
      Google-Maps-iOS-Utils (= 2.1.0) was resolved to 2.1.0, which depends on
        GoogleMaps

    react-native-google-maps (from `../node_modules/react-native-maps`) was resolved to 0.28.0, which depends on
      GoogleMaps (= 3.5.0) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Trying to understand, this maybe happened after you updated google-maps library. So you already have the pod installed locally but it is not compatible with the one Podfile requires.
Probably `pod update` can solve the problem.
You can also get an error on this and probably `pod install --repo-update` will solve it. Then do `pod update` again.